# how to retrieving elements from static array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, for-loop

My array list does not store or even retrieve items back, when the user press rent the it get the value of the item (the id item) and then it store it on the arryList, and from the basket file it should retrieve the selected item by the user from the database using the item id. the main problem i have is that adding and retrieving seems like not working

```
    class Shop {

           static $_item = array();
          public function __construct(){

          }

    public function addItem($id) 
                { self::$_item[] = $id; 

                }
                public function getId()
                {
                    foreach(self::$_item->s as $s)
                    {
                        return $s;
                    }
                }
    }





<?php

require_once('Models/Dvd_sql.php'); 

require_once('Models/Shop.php');  


$view = new stdClass(); 
$view->dd = 'SQL'; 

$dvd_sql = new Dvd_sql(); 
$view->dd  = $dvd_sql->fetchAllStudents();    //->fetchAllStudents(); 



if(isset($_POST['rent']))
{
  $shop = new Shop();
  $shop->addItem($_POST['trying']);


}




   require_once('Views/dvdDetails.phtml');
<?php
require_once('Models/Basket.php'); 

require_once('Models/Shop.php');

$view = new stdClass();
$view->login = 'Homepage';
$view->dd = 'SQL'; 
$shop = new Shop();
 $basket = new Basket();

$d = $shop->getId();

$view->dd = $basket->getFrom($d);
```

Comment: `self::$_item` is array, it doesn't have any `->s` property.

Comment: Also, won't 'return' stop the function -- making the loop useless? (I'm new to php, so I'm probably wrong.)

Comment: @Obversity you're right, it's an error too

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that in the following foreach, it will exit the function on the `return` and return only the first item. Plus since it is an array, it does not have the `'s' property`

---

Since you have multiple items in `$shop`, you can retrieve the complete array and then process them from outside the class

```
            public function getId()
            {
                    return self::$_item;
            }
```

outside the class

```
$shop = new Shop();
$basket = new Basket();

$d = $shop->getId();
foreach ($d as $id){
    $view->dd = $basket->getFrom($id);
    // do whatever you wish to do with the retrieved basket item
    // it's not clear what you wish to do with the item.
}
```

Comment: See above for an attempt at guessing what you are looking for. If my guess is off, try to supply a bit more clarity on what you are doing with $view->dd. I see that you have assigned it twice without it making much sense to me: `$view->dd = 'SQL'` AND `$view->dd=$dvd_sql->fetchAllStudents()`